# Read multiple images from same directory with imageio

Tags: python, python-imageio

I have a directory `test/` with images `0.jpg`, and `1.jpg`. How can I use [`imageio`](http://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#read-medical-data-dicom)'s `mimread` function to specify the directory `test` and read both `0` and `1`? Or is this not what it's meant for?

I tried `imageio.mimread(uri="/path/to/test/", format=".jpg")` but got the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-89a6d166a345> in <module>()
----> 1 imageio.mimread(uri="test", format=".jpg", memtest=True)

/Users/myuser/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py in mimread(uri, format, memtest, **kwargs)
    279 
    280     # Get reader
--> 281     reader = read(uri, format, 'I', **kwargs)
    282 
    283     # Read

/Users/myuser/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py in get_reader(uri, format, mode, **kwargs)
    127 
    128     # Return its reader object
--> 129     return format.get_reader(request)
    130 
    131 

/Users/myuser/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/imageio/core/format.py in get_reader(self, request)
    165         if select_mode not in self.modes:
    166             raise RuntimeError('Format %s cannot read in mode %r' % 
--> 167                                (self.name, select_mode))
    168         return self.Reader(self, request)
    169 

RuntimeError: Format JPEG-PIL cannot read in mode 'I'
```

Answer (score 1):

I've looked at the source code for imageio and I don't see any support in mimread() for iterating through the files in a folder to read in multiple images.  I recommend using scikit-image instead.  Here's an example:

```
from skimage.io import imread_collection
seq = imread_collection("*.jpg", conserve_memory=True)
```

Then you can index into seq to get each image:

```
seq[0]

seq[1]
```

etc.

Comment: Does that mean that for an example using a path, it would be `seq = imread_collection("/path/to/test/*.jpg", conserve_memory=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html#imageio.mimread) says:

> uri : {str, pathlib.Path, bytes, file}>
>
> The resource to load the images from, e.g. a filename,pathlib.Path, http address or file object, see the docs for more info.

Try `imageio.mimread(uri='test')`.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck adding the `uri=` in front of my path. I've edited the question to better show my issue.

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error? Please edit your question and include the relevant parts of your code that we need to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Or is this not what it's meant for?

Correct. `mimread` is meant for image formats that are capable of storing more than one image in the same file. A semi-popular example of such a format is `.tiff`, which has a notion of pages, which may contain different images. Another one is `.psd` (the photoshop format).

If you want to read images from a folder, you can do it in the traditional way using a generator expression (assuming your folder only contains images you want to read

```py
(iio.imread(filename) for filename in glob.glob(folder))
```

or you can be more sophisticated and write something that reads recursively and/or filters files based on your needs.

```py
def read_folder(folder, ...):
    for item in glob.glob(folder):
        if matches_image_filter(item):
            yield iio.imread(item)
        elif matches_subfolder_filter(item):
            yield from read_folder(item, ...)
```

You get the idea ;)

---

Note: It's not the first time I hear that `mimread` is confusing, so if you have suggestions on how to improve clarity, feel free to leave a comment and I'll be happy to update the docs.